# how to get excerpt without p html tag from wordpress post

Tags: excerpt

my site is http://www.examplaza/answers

am trying to use this code to pull the excerpt (first 33 characters of my post) `<?php echo excerpt(33); ?>` but it ended up leaving an empty space.

the theme am using is using

Answer (score 3):

Please add below code in theme functions.php

```
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: Should be removed only to get the excerpt, and restore right after.

Comment: I don't understand this answer...

Comment: thank you so much